# Qt QTableWidget QDoubleSpinBoxes/QSpinBoxes as elements accessing values by Iteration

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidgetitem, qspinbox

I create a table with two rows and two columns:

[image]

The second column contains spinBoxes as elements. The code is the following:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    myTable = ui->tableWidget;

for( int i = 0; i < myTable->rowCount(); i++ )
    {
      QDoubleSpinBox *spinBox = new QDoubleSpinBox(this);
      spinBox->setValue( i + 1 );
      myTable->setCellWidget( i, 1, spinBox );
    }
}
```

`myTable` is declared as a member of `MainWindow`.

Normally, values of just `SpinBoxes` are accessed via:

```
ui->spinBox->value();
```

But this is not working here.

How do I access the values of `SpinBoxes` use them as items in a `QTableWidget`? 
I want to access the `SpinBoxes` by an iteration, hence using a for loop for looping through all Spin Boxes.

Comment: Declare `QDoubleSpinBox *spinBox` as the main window member variable as well as you did with myTable.

Comment: Ja but the probelm is that my final goal is to access the values in the spin boxes by iteration... So I am looking for a way such that I can read out the values using a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A table widget works with `items`. Each cell represents one item (in your case 2 rows x 2 columns = 4 cells = 4 items). As you already did you can set a specific widget for one of the items by calling `setCellWidget(int row, int column, QWidget* widget)`. Now, with the corresponding call `cellWidget(int row, int column)` it will return that pointer to the QWidget you set before.

The only thing left then is to `cast` the `QWidget` back to its derived class.

```
double val = static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(myTable->cellWidget(0,1))->value();
```

As you asked for an explanation, here is the code in single lines with comments:

```
QWidget* some_cell_widget = myTable->cellWidget(0,1);                            // retrieve widget from cell
QDoubleSpinBox* dbl_spin_box = static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(some_cell_widget);   // cast widget to double spin box
double val = dbl_spin_box->value();                                              // get value from spinbox
```

Comment: you are absolutely wonderful!!! Would you be so kind as to explain me why this is working? I don't really understand the code.

Or/and do you know a good page to read about it?

Comment: I extended the answer to give a more detailed explanation

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to do it is in this way:

```
//To set the value:
int valueIWant = 5;
ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(0,2)->setProperty("value",valueIWant);"
//And to read the value:
int actualValue = ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(0,2)->property("value").value<int>();
```

I hope this can help.